# How to slice a string when the slice is an index value

Tags: python, string

What is the most pythonic way to do:

```
"hello"[myIndices]
```

where if myIndices were `range(1,3)` it would just return me "el".

I'm happy to use numpy or other packages. I can do something similar in R but can't seem to get the same to work in python. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slice objects can be assigned a name using the builtin [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice):

> `class slice(start, stop[, step])`
>
> Return a slice object representing the set of indices specified by `range(start, stop, step)`.

```
>>> my_indices = slice(1, 3)
>>> "hello"[my_indices]
'el'
```

Literal slices are actually translated to slice objects behind the scenes. And these are different from `range` objects in that they are not iterable. They only encapsulate the logic with which a sequence should be sliced:

```
class D(object):
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return x

print(D()[1])
# 1              
print(D()[1:3])
# slice(1, 3, None)
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Can you give me some more intuition around "slice"? What does it do exactly that's different from range?